# Add foreign key constraint to existing table with data in a Visual Studio database project

Tags: database-project, sql-server-2014-express

I have a visual studio database project and I need to add a new table and a foreign key to an existing table/column pointing to this new table.  We already have data and I don't want to lose it.

I have a stand-alone table (named Records) and one of the fields is statusID. This maps to an enum in our code so it provides very little value when directly querying the database.

I created a new table called AllStatuses.  The primary key is the statusID and the values are the same as my enum.  It also has the text value (matching my enum) and some other attributes.

Next I added the foreign key constraint to the Records table that references my new AllStatues table.

During deployment the new table is created.  Then it throws and error when the FK is created because AllStatues has no data (yet).

I add data to AllStatues in the postdeployment, but that's to late.
I can't add it in the predeployment because the table is not there.

I am trying to find a proper way to handle this.
I could do a work workaround by moving the Records table data to a temp table and truncating in the preDeployment Script.  Then move the data back in postDeployment after I add the data.  I don't like this because it will happen on every deployment - long after it's needed.

Answer (score 0):

When creating the foreign key you could create it "WITH NOCHECK". This will prevent the violations when the foreign key is created. In your post deployment insert the values. Then the last step is to enforce the constraint using "WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT". My database project using SSDT does this as part of the publish process.